# How to create SPARQL REST API returning JSON?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

I want to create a REST service which returns results of my SPARQL queries as JSON. I worked with Apache Fuseki (on a local host) and there were some options to return the results as JSON.  I want to run something like this on my server rather than my local host.  Is it possible to have something like this (i.e., which returns results as JSON) on my server?

Comment: For example in Stardog you can pass an HTTP header `'Accept: application/sparql-results+json'` to get the response as JSON. See also https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/. I assume most SPARQL endpoints support that.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  If Fuseki does what you want, why not put Fuseki on your server?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Indeed you can write your own REST service which wraps are SPARQL execution framework - I don't see the problem. Java-based SPARQL frameworks are, among others, Apache Jena (this is the core of Fuseki) and RDF4J

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor first, i do not  know, how to put it on the server. second i want an endpoint, the Json that Fuseki  give me, it is no an endpoint, it is some where in the User interface  .

Comment: so, what you are saying is, there is not anything that i gave my .owl/.rdf file to it and then give my SPARQL  query to it just give me a .json file? (sorry for my boring question dear). @AKSW

Comment: OK, so let me tell my question in a lower level: how can i run SPARQL on my server (not local host/ my web host)? i cant see any good answer for that. maybe it is because this level is so easy and they didn't think maybe somebody need guide in this level too (i know my maybe my question is so simple, but i am just start to implementing an ontology in real use for my class; before it was just theory and localhost).@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: It's still not clear what you want. I'll try to summarize it, you have a server and some data. You want to run SPARQL queries via HTTP and JSON as returned format. The short answer is, simply set up a triple store on the server. Fuseki basically wraps the Jena triple stores with some HTTP layer. You should be able to put it on the server, otherwise, I don't see what you want with a server if you're not able to deploy services there.

Comment: @AKSW thanks dear. i will try what u sayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no qualitative difference between running something on your localhost and on a remote server. The program running on localhost to answer your calls locally /is/ a server. The exact same deployment on a computer acting as an internet visible server would do what you describe in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL to your JSON data from Apache Fuseki, select the `.txt` output format, and run. Then it open the page with your query and `&output=text` you just have to replace that end with `output=json`.

Here is my Fuseki 1 ( got pb to install Fuseki2) hosted on OpenShift:

http://rdf-smag0.rhcloud.com/ds/query?query=Select+*+where+%7B+%3Fsujet+%3Fprédicat+%3Fobjet+%7D&output=json

And an app that use it in JSON format (be patient, it takes 1 min to load):

http://smag-cece4.firebaseapp.com/?search=David